# How to get a single gist from github with GET /gists/:id

Tags: github, github-api

Somehow I fail to get a single gist from github.

Lets say i would like to get the following gist: https://gist.github.com/jrm2k6/6637633

Just copy&paste in URL field of your browser.

With `https://api.github.com/users/jrm2k6` I can get the users info as json.

With `https://api.github.com/users/jrm2k6/gists` I can list all the public gists from this user as json.

But how do I get a specific gist `GET /gists/:id` with the id = 6637633  like it is described here in the api documentation: http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist

With `https://api.github.com/users/jrm2k6/gists/6637633` I should receive the content of the gist as json but instead I receive an error

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "http://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

SOLUTION: You do not need the /users/:user. Working: `https://api.github.com/gists/6637633`

Comment: omg thx! I got sucked in by /users/:user...All previous pages/torial used that. Stijn, could you please post your comment as answer?

Comment: Why would you try to get my user profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for all gists mentions

> GET /users/:user/gists

Notice that the documentation for a single gist mentions

> GET /gists/:id

so you do not need a user. `https://api.github.com/gists/6637633` will work.